# JSX get Component by string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

This is pretty complicated to explain.

I am getting a couple of `Icons` from a component library as follows:

`import { Icons } from`my-component-library';`

Let say I've got 3 Icons in there called `IconPlus`, `IconMinus` and `IconEquals`.

I can easily display the `IconEquals` along with a description prop as follows:

```
const IconContainer = ({ description ) => (
    <div>
        {description}
        <Icons.IconEquals />
    </div>
)
```

This works nicely. Now I'm trying to implement a template where I could pass another prop `icon` to this container which would display the corresponding icon.

Eg. if `icon` is `IconPlus`

Then it should render the following:

```
<div>
    {description}
    <Icons.IconEquals />
</div>
```

How do I implement my `JSX` to do that?

This is basically what I've got:

```
import { Icons } from 'my-component-library'

const IconContainer = ({ description, icon }) => (
    <div>
        {description}
        <Icons.{icon} /> // <---- Obviously that doesn't work
        // ^^^^ But I need something like this
    </div>
);
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use like this :

```
<Icons[icon] />
```

Comment: You sure? Because that gives me a `SyntaxError: unexpected token` problem

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle, will you please create plnkr/jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: Ok it's chilled you got me in the right direction. I did it by rendering `<Icon />` after saying `const Icon = Icons[icon]`